# Socket BeginConnect Synchronous execution of Callback in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core

I see some unexpected behaviour, although not necessarily causing an issue, that I would like to understand concerning async socket programming.

It's about the execution of the mySocket.BeginConnect call and its calling of the provided AsyncCallback. With some testproject for network communication, I see that for the same code the provided callback sometimes get called synchronously during the execution of the BeginConnect and sometimes asynchronously (BeginConnect already returned IASyncResult before completion of the callback), with the latter case being the most common (80% - 90% of the cases).

I am however unable to reproduce the synchronous callback call with a very simple test case with socket tcp client and server communication that just spams connect/disconnect calls.

I checked the source code of the .NET Core 2.2 framework and see that the underlying LazyAsyncResult class has two constructors, of which one calls the callback syncrhonously in its constructor. However, I don't find any case where that constructor is used by the framework. The calls I stepped through with the debugger always seems to create a ContextAwareResult which only has a base constructor call to the other constructor. I can in some of these test cases also clearly see in the debugger that the CompletedSynchronously property returns true.

Any hints in which scenario this callback is called synchronously and why?

Cheers.

Edit:

- Testing happened on Windows 10.
- The exact same code on full framework .NET 4.6.2 does the creation always asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified OS you use for tests but supposing the case when it's Windows (for non-Windows I'd say with high level of confidence that the behavior should be similar) it's expected behavior of asynchronous I/O operations. In particular it's not guaranteed that an asynchronous I/O request always completes asynchronously. When it's possible the I/O manager tries to shorten an I/O operation path for obvious reasons (the good example is Fast I/O operations which bypass typical I/O flow via device drivers and communicate directly to memory manager - that's mostly for file operations which can be cashed). In that cases the result can be returned in the same thread regardless the fact the the operation is requested as asynchronous. For networking I/O this behaviour most often can be encountered for the read operations (for cases when data is already read into internal buffer), less often for write operations (for TCP mostly for cases with Nagle or delayed ACK turned on when completion of output operation doesn't require waiting for ACK packet). As for scenario with opening of a TCP connection it's possible when TCP handshake procedure omits network layer like in case of SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH option (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/sio-loopback-fast-path) and [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path/) for more details) which however can be used only for loopback (localhost) interface sockets.

The .NET I/O asynchrony is built on top of native I/O mechanisms and inherits these mechanisms properties and behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however I'd like to know why this change in behaviour between runs in identical states and specifically for this code, since I can't explain it through the source. Furthermore running the exact same code on .NET 4.6.2 executes it _always_ asynchronously.